# Reporting bad review audit

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just got [this review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4881387), which showed me the perfect example of a link-only answer, so of course I pressed the Recommend deletion button, but then it gave me the message that this was actually a good answer. I'm not sure what can be done about these bad review audits, but this one is a perfect example of a *bad* answer, not a good one.

EDIT: I am now, (partially?) because of this review, unable to review further:

> You have made too many incorrect reviews. For an example of a task you should have reviewed differently, see: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4881387.
>
> Come back in 2 days to continue reviewing.

Could this be lifted please?

Comment: Wow...I've never seen a incorrect audit before. That sucks.

Comment: I have, I've had good answers that I was told were bad and vice versa. Not much that can be done other than visiting the actual question and voting/commenting

Comment: @PaulDraper: I have the same problem with a couple of my reviews, lately [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6337086), which – although upvoted – is less more than a copy of an existing answer to an IMHO off topic question. Banned from reviewing now for two days. Assuming the audit questions are chosen automatically, maybe this should change.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What you can do about them is go to the post itself, downvote them and flag them.

The audits are chosen from posts that have more than X up votes (where X is 5) no downvotes, no flags, aren't closed (if a question), and possibly some other criteria.  The act of downvoting and/or flagging the post instantly ensures it will never be an audit again.

Answers like this are also a sign that the question may be close worthy.  I'd normally suggest voting to close it, but it was already closed, so there was no need for us to help in that deptartment.

Comment: That's good to know. I just downvoted that post anyway, so that should solve this particular case. It would be nice if the criteria would also include that the answer consists of more than 2 lines and/or a single code block. Usually that's a dead give away for a not-so-*very* high quality answer.

Comment: @Joeytje50 There are plenty of *great* answers that contain no code, and plenty of terrible answers that *do* contain code.

Comment: I'm sorry if that wasn't clear then; what I meant was that answers that consist of only: either 1 or 2 lines of text, or a single code block, are usually not that good anyway, so the review queue should probably not use them as examples of good answers.

Comment: Would you happen to also know if there's any way for me to skip the 2 day waiting period for having 'too many incorrect reviews'? Or, if that's not possible, to find a list of all incorrect reviews that caused this temporary block?

Comment: @Joeytje50 There's a decent chance a mod will see this post.  if not, you can use the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page to request a manual revocation of the ban.

Comment: @Joeytje50 - I lifted your ban. Let's just say there's something unnatural about the votes on that answer, and I'm dealing with that now.

Comment: While I'm at it, I should also plug this proposal: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188790/135615 for contesting audit cases.

Comment: Why not factor the question into audit choosing?