# Reporting a dubious review audit (is this what we should do?)

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

I [reviewed this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/12702354), which turned out to be a review audit, and I failed.

Interestingly, the system calls it a high quality post (which I'd beg to differ :) ) but I thought the reason I failed it was interesting: the user didn't post a link to the documentation, so when I clicked on the firebase home page link, my first thought was to come back and ask the user to provide a direct link to the documentation and/or the exact steps they followed.

Clicking 'Comment' immediately failed me, with the message: "Your review was inappropriate. This was a high quality post and you should have considered leaving it as-is or even upvoting."

At that point, the upvotes and the original comments became unmasked... where it turns out another user has originally commented asking for the documentation, which was then provided in a comment!

I'm fairly sure this is a dodgy audit, so my question is: should I be reporting this as a dodgy audit, to prevent others from coming across it? I did find [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255834/1982136), but I'm not entirely sure that downvoting or flagging a clearly community accepted post would be the right thing to do.

Comment: So from what i know and read on meta: audits are taken from non controversial posts,automatically. The best way to "remove" an audit is to vote in the other direction... I agree in this circumstance, it doesnt feel like the right thing to do.... Now, my search capabilities are limited atm, but i recall a discussion about how comments shouldnt count as actions in reviews....

Comment: [This one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260803/review-audit-failed-after-just-clicking-add-comment) @Patrice

Comment: It's a great pity FP and LA audits don't show comments.

Comment: _«Clicking 'Comment' immediately failed me, with the message: "Your review was inappropriate. This was a high quality post and you should have considered leaving it as-is or even upvoting."»_ That's dreadful :(

Comment: When I got same effect during review audit and create post on meta, I was downvoted.

Comment: @user2807083 I don't see any posts in your meta profile, can you share a link?

Comment: @rene, I removed it after bunch of downvotes and it was about month or more ago, so post already disapears. The situation was similar - click comment - fail review.

Comment: Depends a bit on the tone of the post and the position of the moon and Jupiter how many down votes you get @user2807083. Glad you found this post so now you know how to handle such audits next time.

Comment: @user2807083 Tone is really important - because a lot of people complain about failed audits / rejected edits / etc., even though it sucks I was really careful to keep the tone of this post constructive. I also mentioned the results of my search and why I wasn't satisfied with what I found to solve the problem. I can't see your post so I'm not saying you did anything wrong - and you probably didn't - but you just have to put extra thought into constructivity with meta posts. The rest is down to the moon and Jupiter as Rene says.

Comment: I voted to close that post as it asks for finding an off-site resource.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I'm not an Android tag follower but the voting seems most often geared towards `I like this` as found on Facebook, not necessarily about the merits of the post.

Given the high number of views and no downvotes it became a good audit. I can understand that you wanted to leave a comment. Unfortunately that positive action is considered as failing and [Review audit failed after just clicking "add comment"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260803/review-audit-failed-after-just-clicking-add-comment) tries to gather support to change that behavior.

Instead of down voting, which was my initial thought, I edited the question to include the link from the comment, moved/included the error message from the title in the post, asked a question and improved some other stuff. I flagged the comments to be removed.

I hope that is just enough for future reviewers that hit that audit to realize it is a good post and choose `No Action Needed`.

Comment: Thanks @rene, that's an excellent way to deal with it!

Comment: And thanks for the link to the comments in reviews feature request too. Totally agree and lending my support to it with an upvote.

Comment: Also worth getting behind [this proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188790/317795) from Brad Larson

Comment: Why should adding a comment _ever_ fail an audit? This is absurd.

Comment: Beats me @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: That's why I'm thinking that this doesn't actually answer the question (not your fault - we need a dev or mod in here!)

Comment: Yeah, that or we need to stir-up the support for those other proposals. Let's make some noise.

Comment: I upvoted the other MSO post and started a bounty [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/review-audits-and-i-understand-button) ...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit moderators will be of no help here.