# Bad audit for low-quality answer?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, not-an-answer, link-only-answers

I just failed [this review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/19537451).

The question asked how to include some data in a file. The entire answer is:

> With your keyboard. Also see, [Create U-SQL EXTRACT Script Automatically](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredatalake/2017/08/08/create-u-sql-extract-script-automatically/).

I chose "Recommend deletion" > "This is a link-only answer", but failed the audit. I'm guessing that's because the answer had a score of +5, despite being link-only (and snarky on top of that).

Can this be removed as an audit question?

Comment: I would have voted to delete as well...

Comment: I think that anything with at least 1 downvote can be removed as audit? (so you can remove it from the audit queue yourself, but in this case ask on meta happens to have better result)

Comment: @user202729 Good point, I didn't think to check the criteria - [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255834/812786) confirms, audit posts have to have no downvotes/flags (both of which I did after I got hit by this).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Let's just say that the voting around that answer was odd. You're right, that was an anomaly.

I've deleted it, which should remove it as an audit case. Sorry you hit that. You're not review-banned, so there's nothing I can do to undo this audit. If this somehow contributes to a ban later, flag and let us know.

Comment: Thanks! Not too worried about a ban, just wanted to bring it to the attention of the powers that be :)

Answer (score 12):

I saw the same audit in the queue. I (wisely?) opened it in another window and discovered its audit-ness and decided to run away, far away (click Skip).

I decided that, perhaps, this was one of those true tests of very high quality auditing - the answer *did* say to use a "keyboard", and our policy is that answers that say "use this tool (name)" are *not* NAA, but that doesn't work so well in the real world in this case. This is a corner case, an upvoted, low quality snarky answer with a link. That answer is beyond terrible, one that should be banished beyond the eldritch gate of primeval blasphemies post haste. It's not really *realistic* to use this as an audit in a world of gray areas.

Comment: I think the sole upvotes make it a "good answer". Sometimes people upvote snarky answers in reaction to bad questions. well, they shouldn't.

Comment: Snark! All of my functions are now yours. Take them!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Hm... that's a known problem. Hopefully it should be fixed with this meta post.